# Trying to distinguish between two strings in regex that are slightly different

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Currently I am writing a python script to load a docx file and then parse through it, line by line. I have two such lines in the doc; Base Premium & Discounted Base Premium. I was able to write a regex expression -> re.search(r"^Discounted") to get the string "Discounted Base Premium" but I am having trouble writing one to pull "Base Premium"

I did try to write one re.search(r"Base Premium"), but that qualifies both strings as expected. I know that there is the concept of negative lookahead and behind assertion but didn't fully understand that concept.

Comment: Why not use the same approach, `re.search(r"^Base Premium.*", txt, re.M)`?

Comment: Negative lookbehind?

Comment: Use a capturing group `^Discounted (Base Premium)\b` or use the positive lookbehind `(?<=Discounted )Base Premium\b` https://regex101.com/r/7XzNNX/1

Comment: But you didn't use a `^` line start anchor in `r"Base Premium"`

Comment: Or you could use a negative lookahead to assert that what you want to avoid is not present.`^(?!.*\bDiscounted\b.*\bBase Premium\b).*\bBase Premium\b.*` See  https://regex101.com/r/STQcPf/1

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise? Are you looking for those exact two phrases, or any `XYZ` and `Discounted XYZ`, or any `XYZ Base Premium` and `Discounted XYZ Base Premium`? In the latter cases, would you know what `XYZ` is? Also, would those strings always appear at the beginning of a line `^`?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Your solution seems to work for what I need :)

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), something like the following:

```
(?<!Discounted )Base Premium
```

This means: Match the string `"Base Premium"`, but only if it is *not* preceded by the String `Discounted`.

[Demo on Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/5LNah3/1)

---

Considering your comments: If there can be text / a product description in between "Discounted" and "Base Premium", and presuming you do not know what this is, you will first have to find that out, by searching for the whole "Discounted ... Base Premium" string.
Afterwards, you can look for the non-Discounted part with the negative lookbehind just as above.

```
>>> text = """Thx for the response :) So if I have my test string "Water No
... n-Weather Base Premium" and put in the expression it matches, but if I 
... have another string "Discounted Water Non-Weather Base Premium" then it
... also matches which is what I am trying to avoid"""
...
>>> dbp = re.search(r"(Discounted (.+? Base Premium))", text)
>>> dbp.groups()
('Discounted Water Non-Weather Base Premium', 'Water Non-Weather Base Premium')
>>> dbp.span()
(153, 194)
>>> bp = re.search(r"(?<!Discounted )" + dbp.group(2), text)
>>> bp.span()
(53, 83)
```

Comment: Thx for the response :) So if I have my test string "Water Non-Weather Base Premium" and put in the expression it matches, but if I have another string "Discounted Water Non-Weather Base Premium" then it also matches which is what I am trying to avoid

Comment: @Chewy Ah, no, this only works if the `Discounted` is directly in front of the `Base Premium`

Comment: Gotcha, which then leaves me to ask if a given solution is even achievable

Comment: I will play around with it today and let you know hopefully by the EOD

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a negative lookahead `(?!` to avoid Base Premium coming after Discounted and use word boundaries `\b` to prevent the words being part of a larger word.

```
^(?!.*\bDiscounted\b.*\bBase Premium\b).*\bBase Premium\b.*$
```

In parts that will match

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

  - `.*\bDiscounted\b.*\bBase Premium\b` Match Base Premium after Discounted
- `)` Close lookahead
- `.*` Match any char except a newline 1+ times
- `\bBase Premium\b` Match Base Premium between word boundaries
- `.*` Match any char except a newline 1+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VXkP5m/1)